# rewrite rule for two folders

Tags: wordpress, joomla, mod-rewrite, migrating, web-folders

I'm migrating my web from **Joomla** to **WordPress**, in order to do so I need to set up access to a new subfolder to install WordPress.

I have a `.htaccess` file redirecting actual Joomla app to subdirectory `/joomla/`. I need access to `/wp/` to set up and test before deleting `/joomla/` directory. Actual `.htaccess` is:

```
<Files php.ini>
  order allow,deny
  deny from all
</Files>

rewritecond %{http_host} ^myweb.info
rewriterule ^(.*)$ http://www.myweb.info/$1 [r=301,nc]
Options FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine On

# www.myweb.info joomla hack
# Add missing trailing slashes.
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www\.)?www.myweb\.info$ [NC]
RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/joomla%{REQUEST_URI}/ -d
RewriteRule [^/]$ %{REQUEST_URI}/ [R=301,L]

# Domain to sub directory.
RewriteCond %{ENV:REDIRECT_STATUS} ^$
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www\.)?www.myweb\.info$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /joomla/$1 [QSA,L]

#No Directory Listing and Browsing
IndexIgnore */*
Options All -Indexes
# End deny directory listing
```

Guess I have to remove or change `IndexIgnore` but also allow `/wp/` access, may you give me a hand on this?

Hosting at GoDaddy, virtual server is Linux.

Answer (score 0):

This will ignore your /wp/ subdirectory on the server.  That way you can install Wordpress in that directory, test, and deploy without killing your Joomla install.

```
 RewriteRule ^wp/.*$ - [PT]
```

Comment: Just to be sure, ^wp/ equals whatever name has my wp direcoty, right?

Comment: Yes, that is correct.  I saw that copying your htaccess file to the wp dir is working.  Glad you got it functioning.

Answer (score 0):

Alter your one rule as follows:

```
RewriteCond %{ENV:REDIRECT_STATUS} ^$
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www\.)?www.myweb\.info$ [NC]
RewriteCond $1 !^wp/
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /joomla/$1 [QSA,L]
```

Comment: Thanks Gumbo, I'll try but so far copying the htaccess to the wp directory is working.